# How to access a DIV on a page being accessed by an iFrame?

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe

I have a print function using JavaScript that prints just the contents of the iFrame and not the page the iFrame is in.  What I want to do is have a DIV or something in the page being access through the iFrame that will go visible when you print and have a legend on it and then it will go back to invisible once the page is printed?  Any help on how to do this?  I am not the most adept at using JavaScript but will try it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the JavaScript. Trying to fiddle the page around a print from script is complicated, fragile and pointless. This is what a print stylesheet is for!

Add a stylesheet with `media="print"` which contains `display:` rules to hide all the parts of the part you don't want printed, and cause normally-hidden parts of the page to appear when being viewed on a printer. You don't even need a scripted print button, the normal web browser Print function will pick up the differences.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.  I decided to skip the iFrame altogether and just do a scrolling DIV.

Answer (score 0):

The IFrame Javascript element has a document property, which works identically to the normal page's document property.

That being said, if your IFrame's framed page is on a different domain from your framing page, you are probably out of luck.  Browsers limit what one site can do to another site to prevent cross-site scripting attacks, and these limits will prevent you from accessing the framed page's document (unless it's on the same domain or you setup a cross-site file on the framed page's server).